# Content behind CoordinatorLayout AppBarLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I was creating a settings activity/layout for my app.  I have a `CoordinatorLayout` with an `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar`, then beneath that it includes `content_settings.xml`.  When the content loads the .xml file is behind the app bar.

I'm using this same setup to load the main content and it works fine, but for some reason isn't rendering correctly within the Settings section.

activity_settings.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_setting" />
```

The content_settings.xml is just a `FrameLayout` that is replaced by a `PreferenceFragment`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/settings_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 73, accepted):

add this to your Recyclerview :

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, I didn't have a Recyclerview, but I added it to the FrameLayout, and it worked.  I updated my question.

Comment: This does move things lower so that it isn't going under the toolbar anymore. However when scrolling down, the preferences on the bottom aren't displayed anymore because the FrameLayout (or whatever you use to hold the PreferenceFragment) is behind the black on-screen button bar (back, home, etc).
At least, that was what happened for me. Haven't found a good solution yet.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the view under the toolbar wasn't scrollable so even though the accepted answer did stop the overlapping it pushed the content down by the height of the toolbar, pushing elements offscreen.
The solution in this case was to also remove the

```
app:layout_scrollFlags
```

from the Toolbar that I was including/sharing with other layouts that had scrolling views.